# Can't play sound " The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type. "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, howler.js

I'm using [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) with ReactJS and I want to play a sound on function call, here's the code :

```
function sound() {
    var salt = document.getElementById("salt");
    const sound = new Howl({
        src: ['assets/p.ogg', 'assets/p.mp3']
      });
    if ( salt.style.opacity = 1 ) {
        sound.play();
        console.log('Check');
    }
}
```

Both problem on Firefox and Opera. Any help please?

Comment: Firefox (and Opera), for reasons entirely based on principle, does not support MP3, AAC, or any other patent-encumbered codec natively. So maybe your `p.ogg` file isn't loading and the it's trying to use the `p.mp3` falback.

Comment: It says here " https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats " that MP3 and OGG are fully supported no?

Comment: Read the footer: "[5] To avoid patent issues, support for MP3 is not built directly into Firefox. Instead it relies on support from the OS. Firefox supports this format on the following platforms: Windows Vista+ since Firefox 22.0, Android since Firefox 20.0, Firefox OS since Firefox 15.0, Linux since Firefox 26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs) and OS X 10.7 since Firefox 35.0."